# Exclude XSD files from NCover CruiseControl.Net

Tags: c#, build, cruisecontrol.net, code-coverage, ncover

I want to exclude XSD files from the NCover report generated after build by CruiseControl.

After serching I came across following option from [Ncover site](http://ncover.com/support/docs/v3/ref/3-0/ncover-console/configuration/profiling-options)

```
<ExcludeFiles><SourceFile>D:\castletech\operations\dev\ncover\resources\setting.cs</SourceFile></ExcludeFiles>
```

However I am not able to put it in the CC.NET configuration file.

Comment: Which version of NCover are you refering to?

Answer (score 1):

It seems all this can be done [from the command line](http://ncover.com/support/docs/v3/ref/3-0/ncover-console/command-line/index), see `//exclude-*` attributes. So, it could be solved by feeding correct command line to ncover task in CC.NET. I didn't try it myself, though.